# Automatically getting AccessToken of authenticated-user in AWS Cognito PostAuthentication trigger event handler lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, access-token

I need to have an AccessToken for a user which has just been authenticated through our web-app via Cognito APIs, and use it inside the code in my custom PostAuthentication trigger event handler lambda function, to update one some user-attributes on the just authenticated user.

How can I get it?

I was hoping that the AccessToken value would already be available to the aforementioned lambda, either in its first [event] or second [context] argument, but it seems not present in there, according to documentation, if I didn't read the wrong one atleast.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. We can not retrieve the *access token* in this lambda. (In fact, access token will generate in a later stage).

In order to update user attributes of the authenticated user, you should be able to use [AdminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) action.

In the *event* argument of the *Post Authentication Lambda*, there are two attributes called *userName* and *userPoolId* as mentioned in the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-shared). These values needs to be passed in the *AdminUpdateUserAttributes* action.

Please note that you should provide the permission in *Post Authentication Lambda* for `cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes`.